# CoreData OneToMany Error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am working on learning `CoreData`, and part of that is figuring out how to handle one-to-many relationships.  For practice, I am writing a simple app containing a list of people.  Each person can have many books.

These are my entities

```
extension Person {

    @NSManaged var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged var age: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var personToBook: NSSet?

}

extension Books {

    @NSManaged var bookName: String?
    @NSManaged var bookISBN: String?
    @NSManaged var bookToPerson: Person?

}
```

The app has two lists, one for people and one for books.  I have a segue set up, so that when I select a person, it goes to a book list, and displays the list of books.  Books are added from the list of books.  I have the `prepareForSegue` function on the people list set up to pass information to the books list.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! BooksController

    vc.person = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(selectedIndex) as! Person
    vc.context = self.context
    vc.fetchedResultsController = self.fetchedResultsController
}
```

On the books list, there's an Add button that displays a `UIAlertViewController` that collects data about the book.

```
@IBAction func addItem(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Person", message: "Enter data to add a new book" , preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Book Name"
        textField.keyboardType = .ASCIICapable
    }

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "ISBN"
        textField.keyboardType = .ASCIICapable
    }

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: {
        alert -> Void in
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Books", inManagedObjectContext: self.context)
        let bookInstance = Books(entity:entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.context)

        bookInstance.bookName = alertController.textFields?[0].text
        bookInstance.bookISBN = alertController.textFields?[1].text

        self.person.mutableSetValueForKey("personToBook").addObject(bookInstance)

        do {
            try self.context.save()
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error saving a book \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }))
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Everything is working fine for adding people.  I can add, edit, and delete with no problems.  I appear to be able able to add books in the manner above, but I get errors when the `UITableView` is trying to display the newly added book.  The errors are:

2015-11-28 16:43:41.911 OneToMany[52183:2082686] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
2015-11-28 16:43:41.912 OneToMany[52183:2083078] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)

When I exit out to the people list and then come back in, the just added book is in the list.  The added books do not show on the books `UITableView` until exiting and coming back in to the list.

I am not sure where this code is going wrong.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue didn't have anything to do with CoreData, it had to do with my adding to Books from within the `UIAlertAction` closure.  I updated my code like this:

```
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: {
        alert -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Books", inManagedObjectContext: self.context)
            let bookInstance = Books(entity:entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.context)

            bookInstance.bookName = alertController.textFields?[0].text
            bookInstance.bookISBN = alertController.textFields?[1].text

            self.person.mutableSetValueForKey("personToBook").addObject(bookInstance)

            do {
                try self.context.save()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error saving a book \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    }))
```

After this, the errors went away and the tableView reloaded.

I found this answer upon further searching stackoverflow for the errors.

I'm still not 100% sure that this is really the correct way to handle one to many relationships in CoreData, but it does seem to work.